# How to add Shipping Rate while creating Order programmatically

Tags: orders, shipping, sales-order, create-order

Shipping Method addition is happening as it should be. But, Shipping Rate as per the Shipping method or, custom Shipping rate is not getting added to the order.

```
$address = $quoteObj->getShippingAddress ();
$address->setCollectShippingRates ( true )->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
$quoteObj->collectTotals ()->save ();
```

---

Searching through some other questions I found a solution which adds Custom Shipping Rate to the order, but it doesn't add the shipping rates to Grand Total.

```
$shippingprice = 0.9;
$orderObj->setShippingAmount($shippingprice);
$orderObj->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingprice);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$shippingprice = 0.9;
$orderObj->setShippingAmount($shippingprice);
$orderObj->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingprice);
$orderObj->setGrandTotal($orderObj->getGrandTotal() + $shippingprice); //adding shipping price to grand total
$orderObj->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's not working, throwing fault.

Comment: may i know what is the fault it's throwing?

Answer (score 2):

did you get this solved?

For anyone running into this, you need to set the shipping costs in 2 places. 
First of all you need to set the shipping method and WITHIN the shipping method you need to set your price. I made my own setShippingMethod function like below:

```
public function setMyShippingMethod($shippingPrice = 0)
{
$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
// Add carrier
$method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
if ($shippingPrice > 0) {
   // use my custom shipping method but you can use another shipment method here
   $method->setCarrier('dpdelivery'); 
   $method->setMethod('dpdelivery');
   $method->setCarrierTitle('Shipping');
   $method->setMethodTitle('outside the Netherlands'); 
   $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
   $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
} else {
   $method->setCarrier('flatrate'); 
   $method->setMethod('flatrate');
   $method->setCarrierTitle('Freeshipping');
   $method->setMethodTitle('within the Netherlands');
   $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
   $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
}
    $result->append($method);
    return $result;
}
```

Then within my createOrder function I add the shippingAddress and then call my method like this:

```
$shippingMethod = $this->setMyShippingMethod($shippingCost);
$this->_order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
  ->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
$this->_order->setShippingDescription('My shipping description');
```

Then of course I still need to add the costs to the order as mentioned:

```
$this->order->setIsVirtual(0)
    ....    
    ->setShippingAmount($shippingCost)
    ->setShippingTaxAmount($shippingCostTax)
```

I hope it helps anybody.

Comment: $this->order is your quote or your actual order object?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$order->setShippingAmount($shippingprice);
$order->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingprice);
$order->save();
```